# Should I change controler when changing a scene in JavaFX?

Tags: java, javafx

I am writing a simple application with JavaFX. I have a `Scene` with three `ImageViews` created with a Scene Builder and a corresponding `Controller` which is referenced from `.fxml` file. On a buttonClick event I want to replace three small ImageViews with two bigger ones. What is the right approach to do it?

Currently I created the new `.fxml` file, copied everything from the old one and deleted one `ImageView`. This gives me a `LoadException`, because there an `EventHandler` in my `Controller` which references the deleted `ImageView`. Should I also change the `Controller`?

Comment: Every FXML file should have its own controller class

Comment: Why you can't do in one controller? Just do everything in VBox for example. After click button, clear Vbox where was 3 ImagesView and then add only two. This change will be dynamic.

Comment: It is recommended to write one controller for every scene because your project gets clearer structure and is better readable. Although if you had a project in which you would have a lot of controllers with copy-pasted code a one controller solution could be better. I would judge from case to case which is more readable and has clearer structure.

Comment: @espendennis If you have copy-paste controllers, you should probably think about creating an abstract controller.

Comment: @MalaKa true. Nice comment.

Answer (score 0):

My solution for this simple action. I used one controller and container where you can dynamically change content. In this solution I created FXML with one VBox and a I changed content after button clicked.

I dont think so that, you should change scene in this case. Of course, like wrote James_D you should have one controller for one FXML if you want to do this.

Controller:

```
public class PictureChange {

  @FXML VBox vBox;
  @FXML Button button;

  @FXML private void initialize() {
    ImageView v1 = new ImageView(new Image(this.getClass().getResource("/smallPic.png").toExternalForm()));
    ImageView v2 = new ImageView(new Image(this.getClass().getResource("/smallPic.png").toExternalForm()));
    ImageView v3 = new ImageView(new Image(this.getClass().getResource("/smallPic.png").toExternalForm()));
    vBox.getChildren().addAll(v1, v2, v3);
  }

  @FXML private void changePictures() {
    Image bigImage = new Image(this.getClass().getResource("/bigPic.png").toExternalForm());
    ImageView vBig = new ImageView(bigImage);
    vBox.getChildren().clear();
    vBox.getChildren().add(vBig);
  }
}
```

FXML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<HBox prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.40" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="picture.PictureChange">
    <VBox fx:id="vBox">
    </VBox>
    <Button fx:id="button" text="Change Pictures" onAction="#changePictures"/>
</HBox>
```